# Вывод нечетных чисел в Java

Tags: java

Есть метод, который выводит нечетные числа от 1 до 100

```
public String printUnpared() {
    for (d = 1; d <= 100; d++) {
            if (d % 2 != 0)  {
                    unpared[d] = d;
            }

    }
    String stringUnpared = Arrays.toString(unpared);
    return stringUnpared;
```

И получаю вывод

```
[0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 9, 0, 11, 0, 13, 0, 15, 0, 17, 0, 19, 0, 21, 0, 23, 0, 25, 0, 27, 0, 29, 0, 31, 0, 33, 0, 35, 0, 37, 0, 39, 0, 41, 0, 43, 0, 45, 0, 47, 0, 49, 0, 51, 0, 53, 0, 55, 0, 57, 0, 59, 0, 61, 0, 63, 0, 65, 0, 67, 0, 69, 0, 71, 0, 73, 0, 75, 0, 77, 0, 79, 0, 81, 0, 83, 0, 85, 0, 87, 0, 89, 0, 91, 0, 93, 0, 95, 0, 97, 0, 99]
```

Как вывести нечетные числа без нулей не используя ArrayList? Как начать массив с 1, а не с 0? Нужно вернуть через return, выводить через System.out.print нельзя.

Comment: c 1 - никак. Вывести - ну так выводите... А не в массив складывайте.

Comment: `d+=2` и не нужно ничего делить...

Comment: @vp_arth это только при условии, что цикл начинается с точного значения и в диапазоне. А если пробегаться будет по какому-либо массиву с рандомным набором - не прокатит

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, прокатит, не прокатит - перед глазами конкретная задача, без намёка на гибкость

Comment: @vp_arth запишу себе в черновичок цитатку, шоб никто не приставал)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я тоже))) Цикл начинается с 1 и заканчивается на 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать ArrayList:

```
public String printUnpared() {
    List<Integer> unpared = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (d = 1; d <= 100; d+=2) {
      unpaired.add(d);
    }
    String stringUnpared = Arrays.toString(unpared.toArray());
    return stringUnpared;
}
```

Либо рассчитывать нечётное число отдельно от индекса:

```
    for (i = 0, d = 1; d <= 100; i++, d+=2) {
      unpaired[i] = d;
    }
```

Comment: `for (i = 0, d = 1; d <= 100; i++, d+=2) {
      unpaired[i] = d;
    }`
Благодарю вас))

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько способов. Неизвестно только что именно вам нужно.

- Например все складывать в строку и возвращать её:

  ```
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      for (int d = 1; d <= 100; d++) {
          if (d % 2 != 0)
              builder.append(d).append(" ");
      }

  return builder.toString();
  ```
- Еще вариант в два цикла. Один раз придется пробежаться и узнать количество нечетных чисел. Создать массив размерностью этого количества и еще одним циклом туда всё запихать.

Comment: Благодарю. Но хотелось бы иметь в выводе массив [1,3,5,7,9...] не используя StringBuilder, просто возвращать в виде int[] или String, а потом уже выводить в main.java с помощью System.out.println("Непарные: " + sum.printUnpared());

Comment: Интересен второй вариант.

Comment: Зачем циклом узнавать, если диапазон известен, а нечетные числа это половина этого диапазона?

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець потому что вначале надо читать комментарии под вопросом

Comment: Второй вариант предложен для случайных входных данных

Comment: @АлексейШиманский В начале чего??

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/downey.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Если вы ни в коем случае не хотите использовать массив, напишите свой класс-генератор. Вот набросок:

```
  public class Unpared
    {
      private static int i = -1;
      private static int stop;
      public Unpared(int start, int stop){
         i = start -2;
         this.stop = stop;
      }  
      public int nextInt(){
        if(i+=2 < stop){
          return i;
        } else throw new NoSuchElementException();

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Оптимальное решение:

```
public static String printOdd (int max) {
    int i = 1, a[] = new int[(max+1)/2];
    for (;i<=max;i+=2)
        a[(i-1)/2]=i;
    return Arrays.toString(a);
}
```

Массив, если хотите:

```
public static int[] Odds (int max) {
    int i = 1, a[] = new int[(max+1)/2];
    for (;i<=max;i+=2)
        a[(i-1)/2]=i;
    return a;
}
```